# How to flatten nested array data into row in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

[image]

I am trying to flatten inside_array or sub array of nested array data into table rows.
I am able to flatten array_data which is outside array.
Anybody have any suggestion.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ... 
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(array_data) AS array_data_rec,
UNNEST(array_data_rec.inside_array) AS inside_array_rec
```

To handle "no data inside the inside_array" - use LEFT JOIN instead as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ... 
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(array_data) AS array_data_rec
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(array_data_rec.inside_array) AS inside_array_rec
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.Does it return no data if the there is no data in inside_array_rec and I try to fetch all column from table.

Comment: see addition in my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. exactly I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

```sql
...
FROM
   AA.nested_array,
   UNNEST(array_data) as array_data,
   UNNEST(array_data.inside_array) as array_data_inside_array
```

Comment: Thanks.This is helpful.